# Program to drive a windows application

Tags: windows

I would like to know is there a way to drive an existing windows application? I want to execute operations in an application like filling out text fields in a form, hitting next and submit buttons, etc. Basically what a user would do, I wanted to automate those operations. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks
Mukul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (with limitations and quirks), if that particular Windows application uses native windows (so-called) controls (UI elements). Qt, for example, paints UI elements "by hand", while MFC applications uses Win API UI native (and expanded) elements. So, it depends.

You can explore application and it's UI elements using [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx) tool inside Visual Studio (there are free alternatives available). Using these tools, you can look up target window class name, ID and other attributes that would help you to find and identify elements of interest using Windows API functions.

One can use [EnumDesktopWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and others, to find window and it's inner control of your interest. Then, using [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can send various messages to set focus, emulate mouse clicks, set text for Edit control, simulate button clicks, etc, etc.

Comment: Can I write programs/scripts using these tools, because i need to create a GUI driven application which reads values from an Excel sheet and write those into text fields inside another application.

Comment: You you really need to work with Excel UI? Maybe you should just open .xls and read file using some library?

Answer (score 1):

You can write such a program using [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx), which allows a program to discover and use the GUI of another application.  It's how accessibility tools like screen readers interact with your applications.